# Как использовать один открытый connection из разных Activity

Tags: android, sql-server

Использую подключение к MS SQL баз используя драйвер jtds (по этому примеру https://habr.com/ru/post/206790/)

В основном Activity я создал подключение к базе Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(MSSQL_DB, MSSQL_LOGIN, MSSQL_PASS);
Закрываю его в событии OnDestroy()
Во время работы всего приложения хочу коннект держать открытым и использовать его в других Activity,чтобы не передавать для обращений к базе с разных activity пароль к базе, устанавливать подключение с MS SQL.
Вопрос в том, как во втором Activity использовать подключение con из главного (main) Activity?

Answer (score -1):

С вопросом разобрался, надо было в обоих layout объявить эту переменную connection как static

Comment: Так вы получили утечку памяти. При длительном использовании приложения оно начнёт сначала тормозить, а потом упадёт с OutOfMemoryError, нещадно пожрав заряд батареи. Это произойдёт из-за того, что у вас первая активити не будет собрана сборщиком мусора, как должно происходить при уходе с неё или её пересоздании. Вам надо убрать коннект из активити и вынести его на уровень приложения (класс-наследник Application, прописанный в манифесте), сделав Singletone-ом. Лучше всего это через DI (Toothpick, Koin, Dagger) сделать, но можно и вручную.

Comment: Юрий, спасибо большое за ответ! Погуглил по вашему совету в сторону Singleton. Но больше вопросов только стало. Сейчас у меня создание соединения происходит в классе AsyncTask. Соответственно на экране прогресс бар и блокировка соответствующих кнопок, которая после успешного коннекта в onPostExecute убирается. Там же обрабатываются не успешное подключение.Подключение должно жить во время работы приложения. А как в случае с Singleton? Что перенести в тело Singleton? Как в нем этот асинхронный процесс обрабатывать и взаимодействовать с ним? Если есть подобный пример, дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку.

Comment: Я попробую вечером что-то написать по этому поводу. В данный момент могу лишь сказать, что и AsyncTask лучше не использовать. Если вы в процессе его работы повернёте экран - приложение упадёт при попытке показать результат работы, т.к. показывать его он будет пытаться на уже умершей актвиити.

Comment: Спасибо заранее, Юрий. Ну поворот экрана можем отключить, ну если Singleton  так же, как и AsynkTask запускается в отдельном потоке, то тогда конечно упускаем AsyncTask. Мне б саму обертку Singleton-а увидеть, что передаем, что забираем с него и как обращаемся из разных Layout.

Comment: Singletone - просто геттер для статической переменной. Тут больше важно где он находится - если в активити - то ничего не поменяется и утечка памяти останется. А если вам надо его ещё и асинхронно инициализировать - начинаются сложности. Надо думать как это красиво и правильно делать, особенно, если вам ещё и процесс инициализации надо в UI отображать.

Comment: не столь процесс отображать, а его результат, то есть ответы от SQL-сервера: неправильный логин или пароль, не найден хост или вылетел по таймауту...Все таки сервер может быть как в локалке (wi-fi), так и удаленно (в сети интернет, тут кстати, надо думать будет потом о работе через vpn). Суть в том, что пока не отработает процедура установки связи (AsyncTask сейчас), то и дальше пользователь не может взаимодействовать, т.к. далее идет запрос SELECT, его результат я помещаю в массив JSON, и лишь потом этот массив отображаю в RecyclerView. Т.е. у меня сейчас три последовательных AsyncTask.

Comment: На мой взгляд тут можно применить BehaiviorSubject из RxJava для инициализации соединения с БД. И сделать его SingleTone в Application. Но надо проверять будет ли оно работать так как я думаю. Это сделает код чище, проще и читабельнее, уберёт ошибки, но придётся использовать реактивную парадигму. Она сложна для восприятия и в некоторых случаях может быть излишней. Зато может получиться что-то такое: `getConnection().flatMap { getDataFromDb(it) }.map { convertToJson(it) }.subscribe( data -> showData(data), error -> showError(error))` - и БД будет подключена асинхронно, и память не утечёт.

Comment: Хорошо, буду смотреть, я пока только первые шаги делаю в андроиде, про RxJava  еще не слышал ничего, покопаюсь...